# plural of nouns, example: malum: mala or malums or both?

Tags: declension, plural

I am teaching myself Latin. Right now I study how to make plural of nouns. I have found some rules online, depending on the ending of a noun in a nominative singular form. The website says that most times there are two versions of the plural. Is it like that? For example, an apple "malum", can I use both "mala" and "malums"?

(I have found only "mala" in a dictionary for apples in Latin.)

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is an illustration of the two options of a plural form rule:

@-a, plural -s or -ae

formula, formulas or formulae

@-ex, plural -exes or -ices

index, indexes or indices

@-eau, plural -eaus or -eaux

bureau, bureaus or bureaux

BUT:

@-us, plural -uses or -i

focus, foci or focuses

locus, loci  [no: locuses]

Comment: I edited the initial post proving examples supporting the hypothesis of two plural forms.

Comment: Pretty sure *bureaux* isn't Latin!

Comment: And for the nouns ending with -um: @-um, plural -a or -ums
1) atrium, atria or atriums
2) maximum, maxima or maximums
3) malum, [mala or malums] ??

Comment: Here they say that the plural is malae: https://www.latin-is-simple.com/en/vocabulary/noun/17795/?h=malum

Comment: @Jan that website contains utter nonsense. In fairness it says "This word was edited by a user and has not been reviewed yet. There may be some mistakes." And boy does it not disappoint on that count.

Comment: You will find the correct forms on [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/malum#Etymology_2), it is generally very reliable. But the real answer is: Forget about dictionaries, buy a beginner's textbook or grammar and start learning about **declensions**. Latin has five or so of them (the exact counting depends on your textbook), and once you know them, you won't need a table for every single word (and the best dictionaries don't have such tables).

Comment: I can't second @SebastianKoppehel's opinion enough. Unverified online resources [range from misleading to outright fabrication](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16315/how-do-you-choose-the-correct-meaning-of-a-word-from-a-dictionary/16325#16325). You can't trust everything you read on the internet (like everything else!).

Comment: My favorite is "malum, A declension, masculine gender." At this point I wonder if the site is a troll site deliberately set up to lead people astray.

Comment: Wiktionary is not a good dictionary. Look: there are two ways how to say plural form of the word index in Latin: indexes and indices, however Wiktionary only lists one of them: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/index#Latin

Comment: @Jan Wiktionary is right and you are wrong. *Indexes* may happen in English but not in Latin.

Comment: @Sebastan: and how about plural form of formula? In Latin it should be both "formulas" and "formulae". However Wiktionary lists only one of them: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/formula#Latin

Comment: @Jan In *Latin*, the only nominative plural for *formula* is *formulae*. The accusative plural is *formulas*. Wiktionary does mention both.

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid the website you're looking at isn't about Latin—these are rules for pluralizing *Latin loanwords in English*. In English, for example, the plural of "index" can be either the English-derived "indexes" or the Latin-derived "indices". But in Latin, the only valid plural is *indicēs*.

While it does have the occasional error or overgeneralization, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/index#Latin) is generally quite good at Latin declension. You might find it a more useful tool for looking up words. But whatever textbook you're learning from should also provide all this information in a useful way. If it doesn't, you should find a better textbook!

Answer (score 5):

No, only *mala* is correct. *Malums* is not a possible Latin form.

What website are you using? It seems not to be particularly reliable.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I know in general? Please have a look at the initial post. Is there a reliable dictionary?

Comment: Very likely an English dictionary that allows Latin and English forms for Latin loanwords.

Comment: @Jan There sure are several: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why

Comment: Thank you for the link Sebastian.